# Getting issue with google place api key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working with google map. I have to plot five different location points as per the given lat long value. I have enabled the map.v2 and created a map key on console.developer site(with the normal procedure). I did it and it is working fine.

But, now I have to show nearest hospital on the map for the given lat long in the same app. I did my code well and I have enabled the google places api for android and using the same key what I had created before. And this is what the final URL I am sending.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=17.445876,78.348481&radius=50000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBG9jAnnWcWNNqYqtPht_c6dY6m-gtw1TI

See the same key appended in the url I am using for plotting points then it is working fine for that but for places it is saying

```
"error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 45.123.65.214, with empty referer",
```

I am trying to resolve it from last 3 hrs. Suggest me what to do now.

Comment: can you tell which key you have generated? `sever` or `android` key to use web API for google search you need `server` key not `android` key. android key is used to show map.

Comment: I have generated android key. But, to generate server key, is it required to fill  this information "Accept requests from these server IP addresses"?

Comment: there is no need to put any ip there.

Comment: Thanks, It is working now..